# Pandas - copy cells on non-exact matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I recently started using Pandas functions, but I am stumped at this problem below:
I would like to copy the values of Tag_1 and Tag_2 of abc and xyz and apply the same to their children based on a substring match (ex: abc in abc_child, this is just a sample data, in my real data, abc could have multiple children with abc_ or abc- as prefix anywhere in the csv)

Any help is greatly appreciated. TIA

input dataframe:

```
ResourceName    Tag_1    Tag_2    
 abc            cab_key  cab_value
 abc_child                        
 xyz            zyx_key  zyx_value
 xyz_child
```

Desired output:

```
ResourceName    Tag_1    Tag_2
 abc            cab_key  cab_value
 abc_child      cab_key  cab_value
 xyz            zyx_key  zyx_value
 xyz_child      zyx_key  zyx_value
```

Comment: try: `df.ffill()`?

Comment: Would `bc`, which fulfills ('bc' in 'abc_child') be considered a substring match ?

Comment: nope, abc in abc_child and xyz in xyz_child

Answer (score 0):

You can try `df.fillna()` like this:

```
df2

ResourceName    Tag_1   Tag_2
abc cab_key cab_value
abc_child   <NA>    <NA>
xyz zyx_key zyx_value
xyz_child   <NA>    <NA>

df2.fillna(method='ffill')

ResourceName    Tag_1   Tag_2
abc cab_key cab_value
abc_child   cab_key cab_value
xyz zyx_key zyx_value
xyz_child   zyx_key zyx_value
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I believe ffill method takes the values of the previous row - that is not what I need unfortunately, what I have is a sample data, these child rows could be anywhere in the csv